# High VLF count even with frequent SQL Log Backups

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

One of our servers is an SQL Server 2008 R2 database (full recovery) of less than 100GB in size that is backed up daily with transaction log backups taken every 15 minutes.  The Log file growth is set to 500MB.

But no matter what I do, I cannot get the VLF count down to a respectable figure (e.g. 50) and is now constantly sitting between 500-700.

I've used the expand, backup logs, shrink, expand, backup, shrink, etc... technique and whilst it works to drop the VLF count from 700 to 500, that is as far as it will go.

The database is partially replicated (Transactional - continuous).  We rely heavily on doing reports off the subscription database and up-to-date reports are run 24-7, so we cannot change the replication model.  We do nightly index rebuilds/reorganising and update statistics weekly.

There aren't any long running transactions according SYSPROCESSES.

I am at a bit of a loss.  Is there any cure apart from temporarily performing a Backup -> Simple -> Full operation?

TIA

Comment: what you see in the status column when you run DBCC LOGINFO('dbname')

Comment: Sorry I should have included that in the OP.  Only 25 of them are status 2, the rest 0.

Comment: Hope you don't have 2 at the end which means that VLF is in use and it can't be shrunk. I am not a DBA but did you tried taking the recent log backup and then change the recovery model to simple and do a shrink , make it back to full and give tempdb enough size initially to avoid automatic growth and keep all your transaction as short as possible

Comment: Ah thanks for that bit of knowledge.  I did not know that shrinking will only affect the tail of the transaction log.  So one could have 10000 VLF's marked as status 0 and only 10 marked as status 2, but if they are positioned at the tail then nothing will shrink.